# Module parse failed: Unexpected token - React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My first time using react, so apologies if I'm doing something obvious and incredibly wrong. That said, I've read up on several similar-seeming bugs on here and on github and I can't find anything that works for mine. Here's the full error message:

```
./src/components/MenuContainer.jsx 103:20
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (103:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(RowContainer, {
|    flag: false,
>    data: foodItems?.filter(function (n) {
|      return n.category == filter;
|    }),
```

The full code from which that error message was drawn:

```
<div className="w-full">
  <RowContainer
    flag={false}
    data={foodItems?.filter((n) => n.category == filter)}
  />
</div>
```

I previously had a problem whit the framer-motion version so I downgraded that and on the next run of the app this is the error that I got , I don't know if it's related or not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error in your `MenuContainer.jsx` (line 103)

It may be because of the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` in the `data` prop. This is only supported in newer versions of JavaScript, and may not be supported by all browsers / Node versions.

Ensure your js version can support it, or maybe try replacing it with a null check/using the && operator. Here's an example:

```
<RowContainer
  flag={false}
  data={foodItems && foodItems.filter((n) => n.category == filter)}
/>
```